# VB - Click Same Button Twice

Tags: vb.net

Im new to VB and have been searching the internet for answer.

Im trying to create a launcher that allows you to simply locate your exe and run the exe.

Problem is that i can't figure out how to have those 2 actions to happen with just 1 button.

e.g: Click " Play " will open a folder where you have to locate your exe, once its located the folder closes and then when you press " Play " again, it launches the allready located exe.

What i got so far is:

```
Private Property TextBox As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox = OpenFileDialog1.FileName("/Wow.exe")
        Process.Start(TextBox)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It works " almost " as i want it to.
As of now, when i press the " Play " it simply opens a folder where i can select the .exe and then when the folder closes, it opens the .exe automatically. When i press the " Play button again it repeats the process. It even launches the .exe if i press the "exit button (top right)" on the folder.

Could it be possible to make it come with an error if its not the correct file that has been selected ??

Hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Private filePath As String = String.Empty

Private Sub PlayButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click
    Try
        If filePath.Length = 0 Then
            Dim diagResult As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            If diagResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                filePath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                If filePath.ToUpper.EndsWith("WOW.EXE") Then
                    Process.Start(filePath)
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong file selected!")
                    filePath = String.Empty
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Process.Start(filePath)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred in the play button click:", ex.Message))
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that it still opens Wow.exe automatically after the dir folder has closed. How do i add a Save to it, meaning: saving the wow.exe dir so i don't have to select the wow.exe each time ?

Comment: Change the scope of the filePath to be outside the button click and private to the form.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. sry

Comment: I would change that to `If filePath.ToUpper.EndsWith("WOW.EXE") Then`, or possibly `If System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath).ToUpper = "WOW.EXE" Then`.  As it is, it won't match if the user renamed the executable and changed the cASiNg of it.  It would also give a false positive if they selected a file that had "Wow.exe" somewhere in its path, but could be a completely different file at the end.

Comment: Updated with @Idle_Mind suggestion. Thanks.